# Nvidia GEForce GT 610 installed via additional drivers changed the default color to blue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS - 64 bit along side Windows 10. When the default nouveau driver was used for my graphics card..the color was purple - default color of Ubuntu Linux. 
When i went to additional drivers and installed the propitiatory but tested driver for my graphics card(Nvidia GEForce  GT 610) - during install, apply and after restart the color has been changed to cobalt blue NOT purple.
[image]

If i use the last driver Nouveau - it turns back to default purple color.

This is how the desktop looks like - cobalt blue.

Any idea - how to fix this? Thanks for advance.

As per the nvidia website -361 is the latest driver for this graphics card
[image]

[image]

**Update**

After 2-3 times restart this issue got resolved on it's own. I am getting the default purple kind of wallpaper with no cobalt blue kind of colors/shades. No change required on the nvidia-361 driver.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to enable the `graphics-drivers` ppa on your system that contains the NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Then you should have listings all the way up to `367.18 (Open Source)` drivers.  Seems to be working great for me.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Were you getting the same problem...cobalt blue kind of color/shade??? With 2-3 times reboot this issue has been resolved now...no change required on the nvidia-361 drivers side...moreover the driver that i am having is proprietary and tested...so i am not going to change unless there are any issues with that.

Comment: @Ashu Not really, but then again, being colorblind I have a hard time seeing colors like that anyway.  I actually like the looks of the cobalt blue that you have posted.  I did, however, do this change because I prefer open source to proprietary drivers.  It was nice to actually see that NVIDIA is allowing for open source now.  =)